# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime Exception

Tags: c#, .net, string, datetime

```
string datestring = txtNewReminderRemindDate.Text.ToString() + " " + RemTime.ToString();
```

So my datestring is "17/5/2017 19:10:00"

I'm trying to convert this string to put my Notification. But when I do this:

```
DateTime alarm = DateTime.ParseExact(datestring, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I get this:

`Unhandled Exception:`

`System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I even tried:

```
DateTime alarm = DateTime.Parse(datestring);
```

Comment: Your format is wrong.  It should be "dd/M/yyyy" not "dd/MM/yyyy"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just replace `MM` part with `M`. The month (`5`) in your string (`17/5/2017 19:10:00`) is only one digit, not two digits. So you shouldn't use `MM`.

```
 DateTime.ParseExact(datestring, "dd/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Thank you. I just feel so dumb when I do something like this.