# How to resolve the error "String was not recognized as a valid Date Time in Vb.net "

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

My code behind is as follows I want to enter the date as per displayed on the TextBox4 front end

```
 Protected Sub btnSave_Click1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim dt2 As OleDbParameter
    dt2 = cmd.CreateParameter
    dt2.OleDbType = OleDbType.Date
    Dim dt As String = TextBox4.InnerText
    dt2.Value = DateTime.ParseExact(dt,"M/dd/yyyy", Nothing)
    dt2.ParameterName = "@StartDate"
    cmd.Parameters.Add(dt2)

End Sub
```

My front end code in aspx is as follows

```html
 <div class="container" id="TextBox4" runat="server" width="181px"  bordercolor="Black" borderstyle="Solid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <script type="text/javascript">
              $(function () {
                  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
              });
          </script>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String was not recognized as a valid DateTime Exception.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44031297/string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-exception)

Comment: @VDWWD Thanks for the link I tried changing the format to M from MM still shooting error

Comment: What input fails?

Comment: Basically there is a button that should select start and end dates from the textbox so I am not understanding why the code behind is not working

Comment: What do the strings in the text boxes look like?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway The problem just got solved I changed the code to         dt2.Value = DateTime.Parse(TextBox4.Text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Protected Sub btnSave_Click1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

Dim dt2 As OleDbParameter
dt2 = cmd.CreateParameter
dt2.OleDbType = OleDbType.Date
dt2.Value = = TextBox4.Text
dt2.ParameterName = "@StartDate"
cmd.Parameters.Add(dt2)
```

`End Sub`

---

Edited like this and it works thanks everyone for the feedback and help.